# How to load view from xib

Tags: ios

I have a ViewController, say VC1, in which I need to load a subview say View1,  programmatically.

I have a xib file named View1.xib, whose file owner is View1.

Can anyone tell me how to load View1?

I have tried the following methods:

In VC1, I call

```
View1 view1 = [[View1 alloc] init];
[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"View1" owner:view1 options:nil];
[self.view addSubview:view1];
```

However, it turns out that the view1 object and the object loaded from NSBundle call are not the same one.

---

Updated:

In the View1.xib file, I have some IBOutLet bounding to the View1 class, so I cannot change the file owner to VC1.

Comment: the `UINib` class has been just developed for you in that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are just loading a UIView subclass that has it's layout defined in a xib then you don't need to set File's owner. Instead you should change the class of the top level object to be that of your subclass (View1) then you use

```
View1 *view1 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"View1" owner:nil options:nil].firstObject;
```

Comment: Oooh very nice one-liner! I didn't know about that `firstObject` property.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to do it:

```
NSArray *xib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"View1" owner:self options:nil];
View1 *view1 = [xib objectAtIndex:0];
[self addSubview:view1];
```

**Note:**

When building a `View1.xib` view in interface builder, leave default `File's Owner` and set view class as `View1`.

Comment: Are you suggesting I call this in the VC1 class? However, the file owner of the View1.xib is not VC1, but View1

Comment: In my view1.xib, I have some IBOutlet bounding to the class View1. If I set the file owner to default, then there is error:this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key XXX...

Comment: Your view in xib needs to be a top level object. Don't connect it as an outlet.